# Dired stopped working (trace with debug-on-error)

Tags: dired

I just installed Emacs on a new laptop, moved over my init files, and all of a sudden Dired+ stopped working.

With:

```
(setq debug-on-error t)
```

I see:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  call-process(nil nil nil nil "--dired")
  dired-insert-directory("/Users/loaner/" "-alh" nil nil t)
  dired-readin-insert()
  dired-readin()
  dired-internal-noselect("~/" nil)
  dired-noselect("/Users/loaner/" nil)
  #[513 "\300\301\"!\207" [switch-to-buffer dired-noselect] 6 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD-e951aa1/share/emacs/25.1.50/lisp/dired.elc" . 22310) (dired-read-dir-and-switches "")]("/Users/loaner/" nil)
  ad-Advice-dired(#[513 "\300\301\"!\207" [switch-to-buffer dired-noselect] 6 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD-e951aa1/share/emacs/25.1.50/lisp/dired.elc" . 22310) (dired-read-dir-and-switches "")] "/Users/loaner/")
  apply(ad-Advice-dired #[513 "\300\301\"!\207" [switch-to-buffer dired-noselect] 6 ("/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD-e951aa1/share/emacs/25.1.50/lisp/dired.elc" . 22310) (dired-read-dir-and-switches "")] "/Users/loaner/")
  dired("/Users/loaner/")
  dired-jump(nil nil)
  funcall-interactively(dired-jump nil nil)
  call-interactively(dired-jump nil nil)
  command-execute(dired-jump)
```

Here's my emacs version:

```
"GNU Emacs 25.1.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, NS appkit-1404.47 Version 10.11.6 (Build 15G31))
 of 2016-09-08"
```

What could be going on?

Comment: Was this a move to OSX?

Comment: @Dan From an OSX to another OSX machine.

Comment: Check the value of `insert-directory-program` (run `C-h v insert-directory-program`) Seems it's `nil`. Not sure how come it's got screwed. Try to run emacs with `-Q` switch and see what happens.

Comment: What does `(featurep 'ls-lisp+)` tell you? If `nil` then Dired+, which you mention, should not affect the behavior here. What happens when you start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`) - do you see the same thing? If not, then recursively bisect your init file to find the origin of the problem.